# Qual é a diferença entre "calloc()" e "malloc()"?

Tags: c, c++, memória, alocação

O que a função `calloc()` faz que a `malloc()` não faz? Ou o contrário. E por que ela quase não é usada? Pelo menos não vejo tanto.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) faz a mesma coisa que [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), aloca memória no *heap* de acordo com o tamanho passado e retorna um ponteiro para o local onde houve a alocação, com um extra, ela zera todo espaço alocado.

Zerar significa colocar o byte 0 em todas posições de memória alocadas.

Ela provavelmente é pouco usada, por quem entende, porque ela é um pouco mais lenta que a `malloc()` e em códigos bem escritos é provável que logo em seguida será colocado algum valor útil nesse espaço, então seria trabalho duplo e a zerada seria um desperdício. Também deve ter caso onde é o que se deseja e o programador desconhece a funcionalidade por isso não usa.

Lembre-se que em C se alocar memória e acessar imediatamente pegará lixo, ou seja, valores que estavam lá na memória anteriormente. Isso pode ser problemático. Ou pode ser o que deseja, por isso a linguagem deixa em aberto. Linguagens de mais alto nível sempre zeram a memória, muitas vezes o *runtime* o faz de forma inteligente para evitar o trabalho duplo, mas nem sempre ele consegue fazer da forma mais otimizada. Já vi linguagem que zera por padrão e deixa desligar isso em um caso excepcional.

`calloc()` é como chamar `malloc()` e [`memset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) em seguida. Mas note que o `calloc()` é "esperto" e em várias situações tende ser mais rápido que fazer separado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Na verdade, ler de um armazenamento não inicializado tem comportamento indefinido. Isto é, qualquer coisa pode acontecer além de só ler "lixo".

Comment: É verdade uma vez dei `malloc()` e li a memoria sem inicializar, resulta que achei 20 reais na carteira.