# Como as funções malloc( ) e calloc( ) funcionam em C?

Tags: c, malloc

Sei que ambas as funções alocam um espaço de memória em *bytes* e retorna o endereço dessa memória, sendo que `calloc` libera esse espaço, enquanto em `malloc` a liberação deve ser feita pela função `free`. Mas, em código, como é o funcionamento dessas funções?

Comment: `calloc()` é igual ao `malloc()` mas ela zera a memória alocada, não tem nada de liberação. O `free()` deve ser usado não importa se usou `malloc()`, `calloc()` ou `realloc()` que muda a posição de uma alocação. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179205/101.

Comment: Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353757/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/345055/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276547/101